# how to copy files from another folder with spesific count in python?

Tags: python, file, directory

i want to copy files from one folder to another one,
I have .txt file & its image  inside .txt have id.
so i want to copy only 100  files to other folder using python script.

```
import os
import shutil
import tqdm
ids=["2"]
path=r'D:\python scipts\yolov7\demoimg'
opPath=r'D:\python scipts\yolov7\destination'
for file in tqdm.tqdm(os.listdir(path)):
if not file.endswith('.txt'):
    name,ext=os.path.splitext(file)
    file1=name+'.txt'

    try:
        reading_file = open(path+'/'+file1, "r")
        for line in reading_file:
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            oldId=stripped_line.split(' ')[0]
            if oldId in ids:
                shutil.copy(path+'/'+file,opPath)
                shutil.copy(path+'/'+file1,opPath)
        reading_file.close()
    except:
        pass
print('!done')
```

my script is copying all images & txt, but i want to set limit. lets say 100 images.

Comment: Does your folder holds one '.txt' file for one image file or multiple files?

Comment: 1 image & 1 txt . both has same name. ex. image1.jpg image1.txt